# ubuntu tweak menus in chinese please help

Tags: language-support, chinese, tweak

I installed Ubuntu Tweak and the menus are partly Romanian (native and system language) and partly Chinese (totally foreign to me). I searched the web, no answer for this problem. I would very much like to know how I can install this app with complete Romanian or at least English menus - NO chinese!! thank you!!

(Ubuntu Quantal / Simple Gnome environment / Ubuntu Tweak 0.8.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no idea if anyone has had this problem, I saw many post from people frustratred by chinese language installed by default in ubuntu 12.10 and taking over even terminal and so on. I'm a n00b so I dont know much about linux.

in the end I solved the problem by simply moving the chinese in Language support down the list (pull). Put English as second language and when I re-installed UT menus were in English (some sub-menus in Romanian) but at least there are no more chinese characters, so, **problem solved**.

I would not delete this issue however, there seems to be a lot of people who experience the presence of chinese support even when the language pack is neither installed, nor ticked as active.

Comment: Please remember to come back and [accept](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1137/44179) your answer in a day or two.  That way this question gets marked as "solved".  Thanks and have fun on Ask Ubuntu!